# ArangoDB: sends "statusCode: 0"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, arangodb, arangojs

Have anyone encountered this Error message, when trying to connect to ArangoDB from a React application [See first attached photo]? It seemed like, it could be an issue related to authentication... but I've tried using "_system" and my own databases, with booth "root" as username and with "root" as password as well as setting the password to "null". I've tried to create new users and tried to connect to the database... Nothing works... (what am I doing wrong? - I've gone through the documentation a billion times at this point).  I will attach a photo of my code as well.
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K04Yg.png),
[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lfaN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the [list of error codes](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/appendix-error-codes.html).  Unfortunately, "error 0" is extremely unhelpful.  However, I see two potential issues.

First is with your use of HTTPS - normally, you use would use HTTP to connect to port 8529.  One caveat would be TLS (like `--server.endpoint "http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529"` with [arangosh](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangosh-options.html#server)), but that's not the same as HTTPS.

Second, your AQL query seems to be attempting to return an entire collection, which is not how AQL [works](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/fundamentals-syntax.html).  Try returning a static like `RETURN 'yes'` or use the format:

```
FOR doc IN collection
   RETURN doc
```